# Tektro Spyre C — is the rotor riveted to the hub?

Tags: disc-brake, rotor

I recently bought the Cube Nuroad FE. I features Tektro Spyre C mechanical disk brakes, and I am underwhelmed by their stopping performance, especially on the rear wheel. I am thinking about changing the rotor and the pads, however after inspecting the bike it seems the rotor is not screwed to the hub but actually is riveted to it.

Can somebody confirm this?

[image: rotor closeup]

Comment: Can you share a picture of the rotor ? You could ask CUBE about it. and have your brakes adjusted; I have them on my bike and they work well

Comment: A picture will really help here. Another interface to attach rotors to a hub is called Shimano Centerlock, and there are no visible bolts but a huge lockring that requires a special tool to open.

Comment: If you are using mechanical disc brakes, changing the housing to high quality "compressionless" brake housing can be a huge change in braking performance.  Cost effective bike builds often cheap out here leaving spongy vague braking.

Comment: Those are center lock rotors so no bolts to hold them on. The rivits are because they are a floating rotor, so not a cheap and nasty rotor. Changing them will not significantly improve brake performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These brake discs are Center-Lock discs. The black "spider" that the disc is bolted to is actually a fixed part of the brake rotor (and not the wheel) with these brakes.

On the right of your image, you can see a "CK" and an arrow. Probably, the full text says "LOCK >" and specifies an amount of torque (e.g. 40 Nm). This is the lockring that fixes the disc to the hub, and the text tells you in which direction and how strongly you have to turn the lock ring tool to lock the ring.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 5):

Rotors are wear items and therefore must be removable.

The Cube website does not specify what rotors are fitted, but I strongly suspect they are Shimano Center-lock which have a steel rotor riveted to an alloy ‘spider’.  They are fixed to the hub with a central lock ring.

Changing the rotor will not improve braking performance, unless you are thinking of replacing it with a bigger one.

Comment: Agreed. Looking at a picture of the bike, it seems to have standard Shimano disc rotors. The rotor can be removed using the same tool used for Shimano cassette lockrings, fwiw.

Comment: Rotors can make a big difference. If you are not dispersing heat fast enough, the brake suffer fade and can warp rotors. Rotor designed evolved from a piece of pressed Steel because of this. If fade and warping are not an issue for your riding, I agree it won;t make a world of difference.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i would have marked this as an answer, too, if i could :-)